# Bundle both x86 and x64 dll in MSI installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, installation

Iam using Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll and Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.dll for screen recording. actually i want to load the dll based on the processor that i have achevied by doing like this and its working fine.

```
private static Assembly CustomResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        log.DebugFormat("{0}, {1}", args.Name, args.RequestingAssembly);
        string InstalledLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        InstalledLocation = InstalledLocation.Substring(0, InstalledLocation.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            InstalledLocation = InstalledLocation + "\\x64\\Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.dll";
        else
            InstalledLocation = InstalledLocation + "\\x86\\Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll";

        if (log.IsInfoEnabled) log.InfoFormat("Current Process envirnoment is {0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(InstalledLocation))
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled) log.Debug("Loading " + InstalledLocation);
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(InstalledLocation);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //EventLog.WriteEntry("IN Application Exception Create", ex.Message + "Trace" + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error, 121, short.MaxValue);
        log.ErrorFormat("Exception occured while loading the assembiles {0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

But my problem is i have to bundle both the dll in my installer project which is currently targeted to x86. when i tried to add this dll in application folder of installer then its throwing an error

> ERROR: File 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
>   ERROR: File 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
>   WARNING: File 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
>   WARNING: File 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
>   Build process cancelled

Comment: Right-click the folder > Add > use File instead of Assembly.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way it works. Different packages are required for different architectures:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

So for 32-bit systems you need a 32-bit setup (containing only 32-bit components) and a 64-bit setup that can contain both 32-bit and 64-bit components:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

It's not clear from your post if you support hardware that is only x86 32-bit, and that's because most modern hardware is 64-bit that supports "legacy" x86 apps. So it seems to me that you might need only a 64-bit build that installs both Dlls. At the risk of stating the obvious, you might need to support only 32-bit and 64-bit clients on 64-bit machines, and not support older x86-only hardware.

Comment: From seeing what he is trying it seems he wants to support both 32bit and 64bit in the same installer, then later in the application using custom revolvers for the assemblies he can load the hardware specific dlls.